# two external css files with the same div ID '#container' name tags causing positioning issues for two objects

Tags: css, html, tags, conflict

I have an issue with two different objects on a webpage that are using an external CSS and external js to call each of their respective functions.
When only one script (a page peel script) is used, the page peel effect display normal on all pages ([www.cxchelp.com](http://www.cxchelp.com)). However, when the script is added to a page that has a CSS form script, the peel effect moves from its position and goes to the middle edge of the page in alignment with the CSS form (See: http://www.cxchelp.com/contact_error.html).

I checked both external script and realise that they are both positioned by '#container'

I know that the fact that they are both using the '#container' is causing the positioning problem. But my question is what do I do to prevent this conflict?

This thing has been beating me world without end for a few hours now, and I am kind of fed-up.

This is (part of) the first .js script (for the page peel effect) where the '#container'is mentioned;

```js
$('#container').prepend('<div id="jcornerSmall" style=" position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;z-index:9999;right:0px;top:0px;">
```

This is (part of) the CSS script for the contact form, and position that both objects are stuck at;

```css
#container {    
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 580px;
  padding: 20px 40px; 
  text-align: left;
}
```

Any ideas here guys?

Comment: Can you edit anything? The JS, the CSS? I don't see a solution unless you change to ID in one of the scripts.

Comment: Can I email you both scripts for you to look at so that you can recommend the edits?

Comment: Here are the links to both codes: (1) http://www.cxchelp.com/peel2.js  (2) http://www.cxchelp.com/css/screen.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class of **`page-peel-container`** to main container of *every page* you want to peel effect. This means the very first `<div>` on the page!

On the homepage, this would look like:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="page-peel-container">
```

On the contact page, this would look like:

```
<body>
    <div id="containermain" class="page-peel-container">
```

And so on.

Now, like last time, find the 2 bits in the Javascript where it says `$("#container").prepend` or `$("#containermain").prepend` if you haven't changed it back after our first failed attempt. Replace it with `$(".page-peel-container").prepend`

Let me know if this still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I will try now. But please note that a div on my main page has the same name. I will give a feedback shortly nonetheless.

Comment: The page already has a div name containermain. Should I still try that?

Comment: Okay no worries, let's try again. I'll be 2 secs while I look into it some more for you.

Comment: Update: It is going back at the top (where I wants it) when the page loads. However, once you point the mouse at it, the effect goes back to the css form position before you can get the peel effect. The form has also changed its position. So its look kind of messy. You can revisit the page: http://www.cxchelp.com/contact_error2.html to get an idea about what is happening. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better solution but if you stick to the first solution, the reason it's moving when you hover over it is that you've only replaced 1 instance of $("#container") in the JS file when actually there were 2. So if you carry on with the first solution then find $(#"container") in your JS file and replace it with $("#containermain")

Comment: No improvement at all. If you look at the codes via the url's I have shared with you earlier, you will notice that I have made the code changes, but nothing changes. I may want to believe that the core problem lies with the CSS code of the form and not the .Js file. Thats just my opinion. Because everywhere that the CSS code is excluded, the page peel effect is working fine. Its just my opinion.

Comment: Update: Sorry. I did not notice that there were two instances of the containermain in the JS file. Will update you shortly

Comment: Changing that final $("#container") in the JS file to $(".page-peel-container") should do the trick. Then all you need to do is that that class to the first `div` on the homepage too (and all other pages necessary).

Comment: The #containermain option in both places had worked, except that it wasn't so smooth. Thus, I am trying the other option.

Comment: Thanks Adam. This is working fine now. I am very thankful for this. My only observation is that it is giving a one second delay or fades for a second before the peel effect gets to work. But frankly, this quite workable. The mini delay is not really an issue. I am just happy that this issue has been solved. Thanks again pal.